# Tableau - How to highlight individual points for a row on time series plot?

Tags: tableau-api

I have values that range from 1 to 9 for time series data from 2001 to 2010. I want to highlight points which are less than 2 and higher than 4 with a color for selected Class (e.g. A, B, c etc. ) on a time series line graph.

Therefore, the user will select or filter the class (A, B, C, etc.) using a list and based on selected class e.g. 'C' the time series line will be highlighted and the point will be marked as RED or Green if it falls in range or out side range.

How can I achieve this in Tableau?

Here are my example data:

```
Class 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
    A   1   3   5   2   4   7   9   2   3   6
    B   4   1   2   1   3   6   6   7   8   2
    C   9   1   4   3   1   1   4   9   7   2
    D   7   4   5   5   2   4   5   6   7   8
    E   2   9   6   7   8   4   3   1   2   8
    F   5   7   7   1   3   7   6   1   4   4
    G   2   2   8   2   1   6   2   2   8   8
```

Below is my visual example showing highlited class line with marked points outside the range as red and within range Green:
Note I made this graph on excel to demostrate the final viz.

[image]

Edit:
I came accross this blog post which kind of point out the issue with Measure value and Measure Names: [Tableau Hack: How to Conditionally Format Individual Rows or Columns](http://www.evolytics.com/blog/tableau-hack-conditionally-format-individual-rows-columns/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pivot your data with column heading 2001 to 2010 by right-clicking on it and then plot pivot field values in rows. 
As a dual axis plot circle chart for the same then create a calculated field using pivot field values and apply the color filter for this calculated fields.
Merge this two chart.